# Plotting: substitute before evaluation

Tags: plotting, scoping

When plotting, the Mathematica seems to substitute the value of the variable only after evaluating the plotted function. To use a simple example where I'm trying to examine how changing certain parameters affect a model:

```
randomData = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 2}];
LogLinearPlot[
 LinearModelFit[randomData, x, x, Weights -> (# + q &)][1],
 {q, 1, 5}
 ]
```

gives lots of errors saying:

```
LinearModelFit::wtsnn: One or more weight values are not non-negative numbers. Weight values must be non-negative.
```

This seems to be because `(# + q &)` is being evaluated before `LogLinearPlot` substitutes the value of `q`, and `LinearModelFit` doesn't like receiving non-numerical weights.

When I use `Plot`, this can be fixed by putting it into a `Module`,

```
(* This works fine *)
Plot[
 Module[{}, LinearModelFit[randomData, x, x, Weights -> (# + q &)][1]],
 {q, 0, 5}
 ]
```

but this doesn't seem to work with `LogLinearPlot` for some reason.

**How do I make `LogLinearPlot` substitute the variable before any evaluation has taken place? How do I ensure that the value of `q` is substituted before `(# + q &)` is evaluated?**

Comment: Your first code runs fine with no errors. Maybe you have some old definitions. Try clearing the variables or quiting the kernel altogether.

Comment: Nope. Tried again in a new notebook after restarting the application, same result.

It does give an output though, so maybe it's actually a warning instead of error. But it still slows down the computation noticeably and generates lots of spam messages, so still needs to be fixed.

Comment: I get no error as well with MMA 11.0. What version are you using?

Comment: Hmm... interesting. I'm still on v10.0. I'll try upgrading and see if that fixes it.

Comment: No error on V10.3.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions. Seems to be a bug specific to v10.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a bug in v10.0 that `LogLinearPlot` has different behavior from `Plot`. Problem fixed by upgrading to v11.0